# Extracting data from TraMineR for use in other plotting packages (e.g. ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, traminer

I am writing a paper using TraMineR for sequence plotting and ggplot for the remaining graphs. I would like to extract the data that `seqIplot( )` uses to create index plots and use it to make an index plot using `geom_tile( )`, for the sake of maintaining the same visual style. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the information (sequences, alphabet, color palette, short and long state labels, position labels, ...) used by `seqIplot` is in the state sequence object you define with `seqdef` from your raw data.

So just explore your object using `attributes`

```
library(TraMineR)
data(mvad)
## create a state sequence object from columns 17 to 86
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[,17:86])
attributes(mvad.seq)
```

Hope this helps